# Embedding multiple bokeh HTML plots into flask

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, flask, bokeh

I've searched for the past 3 hours on the bokeh website and stack overflow but none of it is really what i was looking for.

I've generated my plots already, and have them in html files. All i want to do is embed the plots into my dashboard in a multi grid like formation in the white area in the pic below. However, adding just 2 plots cause them to overlay and be really weird.

[image]

I used the {{ include }} method to include the graphs this way:

[image]

Anyone can give me pointers on how to align them well? Ideally i want 6 small plots in that space. I didnt want to regenerate the plots everytime i loaded the dashboard so i didnt want the embed way.

Please help :( Thank you so much!

EDIT: following big's suggestion, using responsive = True works, but i am unable to control the css styling and the sizes of the charts. I suspect its to do with using the include tag. can anyone help? :)

[image]

Comment: Work is currently underway to dramatically improve the built-in layout capabilities for Bokeh `0.12` later this month, to make them responsive by default. As of Bokeh `0.11.1`, there is a `responsive` flag that you can set on `Plot` objects that *may* help in your situation, you can see examples [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/embed/embed_multiple_responsive.py) and [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/embed/embed_responsive_width_height.py)

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply! response works, but I am unable to control the css styling of it. I think i'm doing something wrong with flask with the include tag :S

Comment: I'd suggest you come by the public mailing list with some example code, it is much more conducive to back-and-forth discussion. Some people on SO get mad at you if you post "Not An Answer"

Comment: I guess I would add, what CSS styling exactly? Most the Bokeh Plot is on an HTML 5 canvas, and has to by styled through the Bokeh API, not CSS. See e.g, http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/styling.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why you dont try to make it with the horizontal layout
[horizontal-layout](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/layout.html#horizontal-layout)

Whith your way ( {% include %} ), i don't find a solution so probably sou must use the standart flask way. Python file:

```
#Your imports
from flask import Flask, render_template
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.plotting import figure



@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    title = 'home'
    from bokeh.plotting import figure

    #First Plot
    p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, responsive = True)
    p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)

    #Second Plot
    p2 = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,responsive = True)        
    p2.square([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="olive", alpha=0.5)


    script, div = components(p)
    script2, div2 = components(p)

    return render_template('index.html', title = title, script = script,
    div = div, script2 = script2, div2 = div2)
```

Your HTML file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link
    href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.11.1.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{title}}</title>


</head>


<body>


    <div style="width: 20%; display: inline-block;">

        {{ div | safe }}
        {{ script | safe }}

    </div>

    <div style="width: 20%; display: inline-block;">

        {{ div2 | safe }}
        {{ script2 | safe }}


    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

And one other tip is to make a python file like my_plots.py
and add your plots there, and then import to you main.py it will make your code cleaner. (i dont know 100% if this will impact your speed, but i don't seen any isues until now ) For example.

my_plots.py:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure

def first_plot():

    p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, responsive = True)
    p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
    return p

def second_plot():

    p2 = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, responsive = True)
    p2.square([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="olive", alpha=0.5)
    return p2
```

main.py:

```
@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    title = 'home'

    #First Plot
    from my_plots import first_plot
    p = first_plot()

    #Second Plot
    from my_plots import second_plot
    p2 = second_plot()

    script, div = components(p)
    script2, div2 = components(p)

    return render_template('index.html', title = title, script = script,
    div = div, script2 = script2, div2 = div2)
```

Hope i was helpful, Good Luck!

Comment: A bit hard to do when you've got over 10 charts, but it works :) thank you!

Comment: @Leo, shouldn't that be script2, div2 = components(p2) or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

Updating Leo's answer as it is for the deprecated version of Bokeh.

- Bokeh v3.0.1
- Flask v2.2.2

**Flask App**

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.plotting import figure

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    title = 'home'
    from bokeh.plotting import figure

    ### First Plot ###
    p1 = figure(height = 400, sizing_mode = "stretch_width")
    p1.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)

    ### Second Plot ###
    p2 = figure(height = 400, sizing_mode = "stretch_width")        
    p2.square([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="olive", alpha=0.5)

    script1, div1 = components(p1)
    script2, div2 = components(p2)

    return render_template(
        'index.html',
        title   = title,
        script  = script1,
        div     = div1,
        script2 = script2,
        div2    = div2
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**HTML Template**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bokeh/3.0.1/bokeh.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-p7EUyPmeDeOwHiu7fIZNboAcQLxei3sWtXoHoShWWiPNUSRng/Xs5JPcaFPRa4dKy9IuHjyIQuLE4caGCwuewA=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <title>Bokeh Charts</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div style="width: 40%; display: inline-block;">
        {{ div1 | safe }}
        {{ script1 | safe }}
    </div>

    <div style="width: 40%; display: inline-block;">
        {{ div2 | safe }}
        {{ script2 | safe }}
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```